# How to remove speed dial screen from Opera 12

Tags: opera, homepage

How do I remove the speed screen from Opera 12 so I can replace it with my homepage when opening a new tab
All other web explorer programs have an option to "open homepage when opening a new tab"
I have read through way too many pages but can not find a solution.
Some programs offer an add-on or just a simple check box in settings menu.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In order to remove the Opera Speed Dial, type `opera:config` into your Opera tab. Click on *User Prefs* and scroll down until you find the *Speed Dial State* entry. The state of Speed Dial is determined by the numeric value of its setting in the following system:

**0** - Hides the Speed Dial main window on the new tab page. A small link will be displayed in the lower right corner of the screen. When you click on it, you will see the standard Speed Dial tab page again.

**1** - The standard view mode.

**2** - Read only mode. You cannot edit the appearance of Speed Dial.

**3** - Disable Speed Dial entirely; new tabs will display the `about:blank` page.

If you want to open the home page every time, simply click `Alt + Home` on your keyboard when you open a new tab. Other than that, I know of no way to do so.

Comment: John, you can access the setting DarkWolffe mentions directly by browsing to `opera:config#UserPrefs|SpeedDialState`. Opera allows you to customise any of your shortcuts, so if you don't like the speed dial at all (try it and you may, I say...), you can simply change your keyboard configuration to have Ctrl+T open a new tab with your home page, for instance, or remove the _new tab_ icon to the right of your tabs and add a _home_ icon instead.

Comment: None of this works any more :(. They reroute all these things to their crappy, broken, "idiot" settings page which does NOT ALLOW you to get rid of their unwanted trashy speeddial. Such a shame.

Comment: I need to do the same for latest Opera. How?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Opera 40.0. This probably worked a few versions earlier:

- Create a new tab
- Click on the gear in the upper right of the tab page
- In the **Customize Start Page** panel that appears, uncheck **Speed Dial**