# How to disable Opera Speed Dial?

Tags: opera, speed-dial

The `opera:config` option doesn't work.  Is there another way to get rid of Opera's built-in speed dial?  I'm using FVD instead.  Opera seems to have a problem with extensions other than their own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove speed dial screen from Opera 12](http://superuser.com/questions/550892/how-to-remove-speed-dial-screen-from-opera-12)

Comment: Mind naming which build of Opera you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [New Tab Start Pro](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/new-tab-start-page-pro/) add-on. Claims to allow you to customize what your start page is. Not really disabling the feature you mention, but shuffling it into the background where you don't have to look at it anymore.

Found via [this forum post](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1864059/disable-opera-speed-dial-in-favour-of-chrome-speed-dial-2-extension).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Opera 40.0. This probably worked a few versions earlier:

- Create a new tab
- Click on the gear in the upper right of the tab page
- In the **Customize Start Page** panel that appears, uncheck **Speed Dial**

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, on version 65, it's really easy. Simply go to the "SETTINGS" Menu option on the Opera Menu (with a red 'O'), go to "ADVANCED Settings", then "Start Page" and then simply turn on "Hide Speed Dial". But this will not work on much older versions, I am certain.

Answer (score 0):

Go to sidebar >Settings(cogwheel)>Privacy & Protection> scroll down to advanced and open>scroll to start page> select Hide Speed Dial and it's gone .